# Stop while loop in thread

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

For a project I'm working on I want to be able to stop a while loop. Here is a simplified script which tries to do the same thing as my script does.

```
import threading
import time

restart = False


def test():
    while not restart:
        print("Thread 1 still running")
        time.sleep(5)

thread = threading.Thread(target=test)

thread.run()
time.sleep(15)
restart = True
```

I kind of understand why it doesn't work, but can't figure out a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what 'restart the loop' means - but I'll take a guess.
Maybe the 'continue' keyword is what you're after?
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it meant to stay stop >.<

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `break`, `continue` or `pass`, maybe?
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm